# How to reduce option for one ForeignKey when there are two different ForeignKey and unique_together is defined?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have three models `Product`, `ClothColor` and `Color`.

```py
# products/models.py

class Product(models.Model):
    ...


class Color(models.Model):
    ...


class ClothColor(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('product', 'color',)
```

I wanted to allow only one combination of product and color in `ClothColor`, so I have used `unique_together` in `Meta` class. This constraint work fine.

Now, I am using `TabularInline` to display `ClothColor` in admin panel, so it would be easier to add a product as well as its colour variations.

```py
# products/admin.py

class ClothColorInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ClothColor
    ...


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = (ClothColorInline,)
```

And, this is how my [admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrxzZ.png) looks.

Now, when I add new color to the color field in `clothColor`, it also displays already used color. [img: drop down menu in admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI0Pm.png).

Due to the `unique_together` constraint it [shows me error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlKoM.png), thus, it prevents accidently fill same color twice, but I need a way to hide the option altogether if the color is already used.

So, how can I reduce the option in color field when I have already used that color?

Comment: Inject js code in admin to manipulate subsequent select options